# How to restore the /etc/init.d/pure-ftpd-mysql?

Tags: debian, sysvinit, restore

By a mistake... this is my new /etc/init.d/pure-ftpd-mysql:

```
    /etc/init.d/pure-ftpd-mysql restart
```

How to install or recover the file? The standard `apt-get remove`, `apt-get install` or `apt-get install --reinstall pure-ftpd-common pure-ftpd-mysql` doesn’t give me that file back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the binary .deb file, you can use [Midnight commander (mc)](http://www.midnight-commander.org/) from the shell to just navigate inside and retrieve files from it.

For your convenience, this is the file as found in `pure-ftpd-mysql_1.0.36-1.1_i386.deb`:

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          pure-ftpd-mysql
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Should-Start:      slapd mysql postgresql-8.3 postgresql-8.4
# Should-Stop:       slapd mysql postgresql-8.3 postgresql-8.4
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
### END INIT INFO
#
# pure-ftpd     starts and stops the pure-ftpd ftp daemon
#
# Copyright 2002-2011 by Stefan Hornburg (Racke) <racke@linuxia.de>

PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
NAME=pure-ftpd
DESC="ftp server"
: ${SSDAEMONLOGOPTS:="--quiet"}
UPLOADDAEMON=/usr/sbin/pure-uploadscript
UDNAME=pure-uploadscript
UDDESC="ftp upload handler"
WRAPPER=/usr/sbin/pure-ftpd-wrapper

# load LSB init-functions to get status_of_proc helper
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

PIDFILE=/var/run/pure-ftpd/pure-ftpd.pid

# try to figure with suffix this script is called,
# $0 might be a symlink pointing to this script
if [ -h $0 ]; then
        ME=`/bin/readlink $0`
else
        ME=$0
fi

SUFFIX=`basename $ME | sed -ne 's/^pure-ftpd-\(.*\)/\1/p'`
if [ "$SUFFIX" ] ; then
        DAEMON=/usr/sbin/pure-ftpd-$SUFFIX
else
        DAEMON=/usr/sbin/pure-ftpd
fi

export STANDALONE_OR_INETD=inetd
export VIRTUALCHROOT=
test -r /etc/default/pure-ftpd-common && . /etc/default/pure-ftpd-common

if [ "$VIRTUALCHROOT" = "true" ]; then
        if [ "$SUFFIX" ]; then
                SUFFIX="$SUFFIX-virtualchroot"
        else
                SUFFIX="virtualchroot"
        fi
fi

test -x $DAEMON || exit 0
test -x $WRAPPER || exit 0

set -e

if [ ! -e `dirname $PIDFILE` ];then
       mkdir `dirname $PIDFILE`
fi

start_uploadscript() {
        if [ "$UPLOADSCRIPT" -a "$STANDALONE_OR_INETD" != inetd ] && \
                egrep -i '^[    ]*(yes|1|on)[   ]*' /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/CallUploadScript > /dev/null 2>&1
        then
                UOPTS=""
                test "$UPLOADUID" && UOPTS="$UOPTS -u $UPLOADUID"
                test "$UPLOADGID" && UOPTS="$UOPTS -g $UPLOADGID"
                echo -n "$1 $UDDESC: "
                start-stop-daemon --start $SSDAEMONLOGOPTS --oknodo \
                        --exec $UPLOADDAEMON -- -r "$UPLOADSCRIPT" -B $UOPTS
                echo "$UDNAME."

        fi
}

case "$1" in
  start)
        test "$STANDALONE_OR_INETD" = standalone || exit 0
        echo -n "Starting $DESC: "
        start-stop-daemon --start $SSDAEMONLOGOPTS --pidfile "$PIDFILE" \
                --exec $WRAPPER -- $SUFFIX
        start_uploadscript Starting
        ;;
  stop)
        echo -n "Stopping $DESC: "
        start-stop-daemon --stop $SSDAEMONLOGOPTS --oknodo \
                --pidfile "$PIDFILE"
        start-stop-daemon --stop $SSDAEMONLOGOPTS --oknodo --exec $UPLOADDAEMON
        echo "$NAME."
        ;;
  restart|force-reload)
        test "$STANDALONE_OR_INETD" = standalone || exit 0
        echo -n "Restarting $DESC: "
        start-stop-daemon --stop $SSDAEMONLOGOPTS --oknodo \
                --pidfile "$PIDFILE"
        start-stop-daemon --stop $SSDAEMONLOGOPTS --oknodo --exec $UPLOADDAEMON
        sleep 1
        start-stop-daemon --start $SSDAEMONLOGOPTS --pidfile "$PIDFILE" \
                --exec $WRAPPER -- $SUFFIX
        start_uploadscript Restarting
        ;;
  status)
        status_of_proc -p /var/run/pure-ftpd/pure-ftpd.pid $DAEMON $NAME && exit 0 || exit $?
        ;;
  *)
        N=/etc/init.d/$NAME
        echo "Usage: $N {start|stop|restart|force-reload|status}" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `hack the .deb`... works fine for me. \o/

Have a good weekend!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove the file with `rm` and then re-install the package?

If it doesn't work, you can try `aptitude purge` or `apt-get remove --purge` to remove the package and all its configuration files. Then, install it again and you will get the default configuration file.

If nothing works, try to get the `.deb` file from the repo (look fo it in packages.debian.org), and untar it twice (first, the `.deb` package, and then the `data.tar.gz` that will be included inside the `.deb`. You must find the configuration file there.

Comment: Frankly, I'd suggest opening the deb (with something like `mc` which does the unpacking transparently for you and can view and copy files out of there) over remove-reinstall, because it's pretty sure to be less-destructive.

Comment: @JoseLSegura Thanks for your answer. Yes: I've removed the file before reinstall the package. The installer doesn't create a new copy. I think `purge` is not the best solution in this case: `running system vs. one missing textfile`.

Answer (score 0):

just create an empty file before re-installing

```
sudo touch /etc/init.d/pure-ftpd-mysql
```

then reinstall with --purge flag (it removes a library with this file, and creates a new work file)

```
sudo apt-get remove pure-ftpd-mysql --purge

sudo apt-get install pure-ftpd-mysql
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix&Linux!  The above essentially duplicates another answer and adds no new content.  Please don’t post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.  But also, we’re looking for comprehensive, high-quality answers that provide some explanation and context.  Don’t just give a bunch of `sudo` commands; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations, and at the very least with sentences.  Answers that don’t include explanations may be removed.